# strange process take a lot of CPU ! virus?

Tags: cpu-load, top

I have Ubuntu 22.04 server, running Apache, MariaBD, PHP, and a web app, facing to the Internet.

Recently, the server always run 99% CPU, `top` command give the output as **attached picture below**.
The `dev` user is one of user in `www-data` group which can run the web app.

that strange process of `hssnRJdAdu` take almost 400% of CPU.

Is that virus?

I installed clamav, scanned, and no infection detected.

Top output screenshot:

[image: top output screenshot]

Comment: What is the output of `ps -fp 30078` ... Where `30078` is the PID of the `hssnRJdAdu` process.

Comment: That might be a cryptominer exploiting a recent PHP vulnerability. Run `gcore 30078` and then look at `strings ./core` for anything suspicious

Comment: after upgrade packages using **apt update** and **apt upgrade** . I reboot the server, and that strange thing did not re-occur. I did not run **ps -fp 30078** or **gcore 30078** . the process is not there anymore after reboot. Will do when it comes back.